# Edit a deployed application using tomcat server

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, tomcat, edit

Last year I deployed an appliction on a Tomcat 8 Server. The application misses some functions and has to be updated. Unfortunately the Maven project made in Eclipse is lost. So the question is, is it possible to add functions in a deployed appliction?

I hope someone can help me!

Project specs:
-Built in Eclipse IDE for JAVA EE Developers
-JDK 7
-Deployed on Tomcat 8 server

Comment: You can't "add functions", but you can replace/add .class and .jsp files.

Comment: Do you mean you lost *all* the source files?

Comment: The source files were on Git, unfortunately the university deleted all the files.

Answer (score 0):

Decompile the class file, add your function and replace it in war and redeploy. Here is a good java decompiler: http://www.showmycode.com/